# How to fix “The ConnectionString property has not been initialized”

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, connection

Hi everyone ı hade a bug about this methots ı use connection string a xml file. firt line is my xml file  when ı run to code it's not
working  ı think this code right but ı can't find where is the bug

this is connection string

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 
   <conn>
     <Dbconn>
     <cstring>Server=DESKTOP-DSGBABB;Trusted_Connection=True ;database=master</cstring>
     </Dbconn>
  </conn>
```

this is my code

```
 private void materialFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CreateDB();
                   }
    
     public void CreateDB()
            {
                XmlTextReader reader = null;
                reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
    
    
                reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "cstring")
                        {
                            conn = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                    } 
    
                    using (connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                    {
                        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
    
                            connection.Open();
                        }
                        str = "CREATE DATABASE uc ON PRIMARY " +
                        "(NAME = uc, " +
                       "FILENAME = 'C:\\uc.mdf', " +
                        "SIZE = 3MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
                       "LOG ON (NAME = uc_Log, " +
                        "FILENAME = 'C:\\uc.ldf', " +
                        "SIZE = 1MB, " +
                        "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
                        "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
                         
                        connection.Close();
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, connection);
                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Veritabanı Başarıyla Oluşturuldu");
    
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            lbls.Text = @"Error occured. 
                      + " + ex.Message.ToString();
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
    
            }
```

> **ı will wait for your help**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried debugging? Or writing some values to the console? What is the value of `conn` after you read it from the XML, before sending to `SqlConnection`?

Comment: yes ı tried to debug but ı cant find.ı didnt write any values ı try to create new database .

Comment: I suggest you debug and take a closer look at the `conn` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your connection string as follows:

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-DSGBABB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;
```

So the XML will be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<conn>
    <Dbconn>
        <cstring>Data Source=DESKTOP-DSGBABB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;</cstring>
    </Dbconn>
</conn>
```

It is much easier to use LINQ to XML API while dealing with XML.

Here is how to retrieve a connection string from the XML file.

Additionally, the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` type will validate correctness of the connection string.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string configFile = @"e:\Temp\configXMLFile.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(configFile);
        
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.ConnectionString = xdoc.Descendants("Dbconn").Elements("cstring").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i fixed it. that's bug very different.it didn't read conn string.i made a diffrent way.